# Comment nomme-t-on la partie affichée d'un texte plus long sur support informatique ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, informatique, formulation

Dans une interface informatique, comment appelle-t-on, le cas échéant, la partie de texte **affichée** d'un texte plus long auquel on accède en cliquant ou avec des trucs comme « voir plus ». Ou simplement présentée dans un affichage, comme ici dans la vue « active » du site on voit essentiellement les deux premières lignes d'une question, ou lorsqu'on effectue une recherche sur un moteur et qu'il nous présente un extrait de chaque résultat etc. ?

Comment: ***L'accroche** d'un article* https://fr.wikihow.com/%C3%A9crire-l%27accroche-d%27un-article-de-presse

Comment: Aucun problème, vous êtes libre de faire comme bon vous semble :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je pense que le terme le plus courant pour cela est "chapô" (ou son orthographe plus habituelle : "chapeau"). Selon [Wikitionnary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chap%C3%B4) : *Texte court coiffant un article, généralement typographié en gras, pour amener le lecteur à entrer dans l’article*. Ça pourrait aussi être un "en-tête".

Answer (score 1):

Lorsque ce passage est généré manuellement, je proposerais :

- résumé
- extrait (1)
- introduction

(1) : l'extrait peut être n'importe ou, il est vrai. c'est toutefois le terme qu'utilise amazone pour les extrait d'ebook, qui correspondent toujours aux premières pages, premiers chapitres

souvent le découpage est fait par la machine de façon arbitraire, je proposerais

- début

mais, en vérité, en bon français le terme officiel est

- teaser.

Comment: Je pense que "teaser" (qui n'a je pense rien d'officiel et que je pourrais difficilement qualifier de bon français) ne correspond pas à la même chose...

Comment: "teaser" n'est pas (encore) français, il pourrait se traduite pas "bande annonce" qui s'applique difficilement à un média écrit.

Comment: Donc le "bon français" et "terme officiel" de la réponse étaient sarcastiques ? Si oui il faudrait le préciser je pense...

Comment: Mais _teaser_ pour la bande annonce c'est _teaser trailer_ où l'on omet _trailer_ non ? Voir plutôt [_aguiche_](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8400655) ou [_accroche_](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44700/26366).

Answer (score 0):

> L'[*accroche*](https://fr.wikihow.com/%C3%A9crire-l%27accroche-d%27un-article-de-presse) d'un article. [*Personne*, en [commentaire]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44676/comment-nomme-t-on-la-partie-affich%C3%A9e-dun-texte-plus-long-sur-support-informati#comment91092_44676)